# Stop page scaling after a certain point

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stop my site from looking all messed up when I scale the window down, or use mobile. Twitter has pretty much the thing I'm looking for. The site will scale up just fine, but if you make the window smaller than for example 600x360, it stops scaling.

I put together a little jsfiddle with what I have so far, but it only seems to work (kinda) on text. I want the background to stop scaling too.

I really appreciate any help :)

Edit: Here is a .gif of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slBJ2.jpg (really laggy)

Edit 2: Here is the JSfiddle I forgot about.. : https://jsfiddle.net/t7ddhtLx/1/

```
CSS
body {
  background-image:         url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPXJDjmUMAA2oE3.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-width: 360px;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1800px;
  max-height: 720px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <center>
  <h1>
   hellooo!
  </h1>
 </center>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the JSFiddle :)

Comment: Thanks :P Added the link now :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Eh, sorry about that.. Just figured it wasn't needed since I included it in the jsfiddle. Ill add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `background-position` to be set to the left, as centering it will always cause the browser to try and... well... center it. If the viewport is smaller than the image this causes the background-image to move. Incase you want to keep the centered `background-position` you can also use mediaqueries to change the position when the viewport gets smaller.

Here's a snippet (view in full page* and change the browser size to see the effect):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPXJDjmUMAA2oE3.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1800px;
  max-height: 720px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-size: 600px;
    background-position: top left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center>
    <h1>
      hellooo!
    </h1>
  </center>
</body>
```

*)Run code snippet -> Full Page

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I have tested in Safari and Firefox. I think you might have misunderstood what I wanted, because I dont think its because of my browser.. Here is how it looks for me: https://imgur.com/a/yZAKK

Comment: Well, if you're only changing the **width** of the viewport it works. Which is all you would need in order to make it look like you wanted on mobile devices. I edited my code snippet however to also take height into consideration. Hopefully I'm not totally missing the point haha.

Comment: Hmm, i tested this on a Chromebook I had laying around and It worked like I wanted it to... (really wonky though) But why won't it work on the Mac Im currently using? o.0 EDIT: For some reason it worked now.. But it seems to scale down, then it resizes the image after a .5 second delay.. Is that fixable? Thanks for the help man :)

Comment: Can you make a gif of that, too? I can't really reproduce this unfortunately. Though it probably won't be visible that much with the low framerate the videos have you uploaded before...Is it on the mac only?

Comment: Nope, this happens on Windows (chrome) ChromeOS (chrome) Mac (Firefox, Safari). Im looking for gif making software atm that isn't laggy, so expect one shortly :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BDxW7 (still low quality, but I think you should be able to see whats going on :))

Comment: Gotcha, thanks man. It should be gone for the most part now. I say for the most part, because when the scrollbars appear, there is always going to be a little bit of a clear cut, which can not be removed.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I just remembered something.. xD Its not just the background I want to stop scaling, its the objects too.. How would I go about that?

Comment: Hard for me to say, as the text you provided in the snippet is not moving. I'd recommend asking another question where you provide the elements you want to stop moving. If your body has a min-width of 600px all elements inside it that don't have position:fixed or position:absolute should already stay in the same place. At least I can't think of any case.

Comment: You can add the link to the new question here and I'll take a look at it, if you want.